# command for automatically indexing

Tags: indexing

I'm finishing up my Master's thesis and need to auto-index all similar terms after identifying the first one. ex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex
\begin{document}

%%%page1

\section{blah blah}

I'm **finishing** \index{finishing} up my thesis. 
%.....
%....

%%% page2

Before **finishing**  my thesis..

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I want to include automatically the term **finishing** on page 2 (or other pages) in my index. Something like that:

> Index
>
> finishing, 1, 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know there are no general tools for this, although if your words are always enclosed in `**...**` then you could do this with `sed -i .bak 's/\*\*\([a-zA-Z]*\)\*\*/**\1** \\index{\1}/g' filename.tex`.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136115/2891